# how to change a drop down options to default selected using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below code is part of my a html form drop down menu:

```
<div class="wrap-quest-resp" id="fa8">
    <div class="input-quest-no-height">FA and port - 8</div>
    <div class="input-resp-no-height">
        <select id="fa-select-8" name="fa-select-8">
        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Dir</option>
        <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==1)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
        <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==2)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >2</option>
        <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==3)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >3</option>
        <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==4)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >4</option>
        <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==5)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >5</option>
        </select>

        <select id="proc-select-8" name="proc-select-8">
        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Proc</option>
        <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-8']==a) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >a</option>
        <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-8']==b) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >b</option>
        </select>

        <select id="port-select-8" name="port-select-8">
        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Port</option>
        <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-8']==0) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >0</option>
        <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-8']==1) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I a using  this jquery  to hide above mentioned div and its drop down selection

```
$('#fa8').slideUp("fast");
```

I would like to change the `option` selected to its default `SELECTED` option while hiding the `div` . That is to below options for all three drop down menus

```
<option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Dir</option>
<option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Proc</option>
<option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Port</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you appear to want all of the selects to go to their default values, I'd suggest using this:

```
$('#fa8').find("select").find("option:first").prop("selected", true);
```

Depending on how your code is implemented, you could make it part of a callback, as ***tymeJV*** suggested, or simply place it on the next line after the `slideUp` call in the code.

If you use the callback, you can use `$(this)` instead of  `$('#fa8')`:

```
$('#fa8').slideUp("fast", function() {
    $(this).find("select").find("option:first").prop("selected", true);
});
```

If you go for the "multi-line" approach, store off the selector for `$('#fa8')` in a variable, so that you are not running the select twice:

```
var $wrapReqResp = $('#fa8');

$wrapReqResp.slideUp("fast");
$wrapReqResp.find("select").find("option:first").prop("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the callback from `slideUp` and set the 0 index of each to selected via `prop()`

```
$('#fa8').slideUp("fast", function() {
    //Set the 0 index as selected
    $("#fa-select-8 option").eq(0).prop("selected", true);
    //do the same for the rest, change the ID
});
```